# Delete nodes which have a greater value on right side

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Delete nodes which have a greater value on right side

Given a singly linked list, remove all the nodes which have a greater value on right side.

**Examples:**

a) The list 12->15->10->11->5->6->2->3->NULL should be changed to 15->11->6->3->NULL. Note that 12, 10, 5 and 2 have been deleted because there is a greater value on the right side.

When we examine 12, we see that after 12 there is one node with value greater than 12 (i.e. 15), so we delete 12.
When we examine 15, we find no node after 15 that has value greater than 15 so we keep this node.
When we go like this, we get 15->6->3

b) The list 10->20->30->40->50->60->NULL should be changed to 60->NULL. Note that 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 have been deleted because they all have a greater value on the right side.

c) The list 60->50->40->30->20->10->NULL should not be changed.

I have written the function for it. But it's not working.

```
void remove_lower(struct node** head_ref)
{
   struct node* current = (*head_ref);

   if(current != NULL && current->next != NULL)
     return ;

   struct node* temp;

   while(current->next != NULL)
   {
      if(current->data > current->next->data)
      {
        temp = current->next;
        current = temp->next;
        free(temp);
      }
      else
         current = current->next;
   }
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect and what output do you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm**  Here is My Algorithm which time complexity is `O(n)`

1. Reverse the list.
2. Traverse the reversed list. Keep max till now. If next node < max, then delete the next node, otherwise max = next node.
3. Reverse the list again to retain the original order.

   ```
   void reverseList(struct node **headref);
   void _delLesserNodes(struct node *head);

   /* Deletes nodes which have a node with greater value node
   on left side */
   void delLesserNodes(struct node **head_ref)
   {
       /* 1) Reverse the linked list */
       reverseList(head_ref);

       /* 2) In the reversed list, delete nodes which have a node
            with greater value node on left side. Note that head
            node is never deleted because it is the leftmost node.*/
       _delLesserNodes(*head_ref);

      /* 3) Reverse the linked list again to retain the
            original order */
       reverseList(head_ref);
   }

   /* Deletes nodes which have greater value node(s) on left side */
   void _delLesserNodes(struct node *head)
   {
       struct node *current = head;

       /* Initialize max */
       struct node *maxnode = head;
       struct node *temp;

       while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL)
       {
            /* If current is smaller than max, then delete current */
            if(current->next->data < maxnode->data)
            {
                 temp = current->next;
                 current->next = temp->next;
                 free(temp);
            }

            /* If current is greater than max, then update max and
               move current */
            else
            {
                 current = current->next;
                 maxnode = current;
            }

       }
   }
   //***********************************************

   void reverseList(struct node **headref)
   {
       struct node *current = *headref;
       struct node *prev = NULL;
       struct node *next;
       while(current != NULL)
       {
           next = current->next;
           current->next = prev;
           prev = current;
           current = next;
       }
       *headref = prev;
   }
   ```

Please Let me know, if there any mistake.

Comment: While this is nice solution, but do respect the [original](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-nodes-which-have-a-greater-value-on-right-side/) author/post !

Answer (score 2):

You should track "previous" item and update its "next" pointer, otherwise you'll break the list while deleting some element which is not first in the list. Also you algorithm deletes all the "next" elements which are "greater" than current element. According to your description you were going to remove "current" element if it has a greater element on its right side. So you should delete "current" element, not next element.

I would suggest the following approach (checked at [ideone](http://ideone.com/m32mf1)) to this algorithm (unfortunately, `O(N^2)`):

```
void remove_lower(struct node** head_ref)
{
  struct node* current = (*head_ref);
  if(current == NULL || current->next == NULL)
    return ;

  struct node* prev = NULL, *next = NULL, *temp = NULL;
  while(current->next != NULL)
  {
    next = current->next;
    temp = next;
    /* check if there is any element greater than current */
    while(temp->next != NULL) {
        if (temp->data > current->data) {
            /* 
             * if some element is greater than current, then
             * delete current element
             */
            free(current);
            current = NULL;
            if (prev == NULL) {
                /* it was the first element, need to update the head */
                *head_ref = next;
            } else {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    /* if current element was not deleted */
    if (current != NULL) {
        prev = current;
    }
    current = next;
  }
}
```

Output:

Input data:

```
2->7->1->36->6->0->5->-1->16->4->-2->3->-3->4->2->-4->1->-5->0->0->NULL
```

Output data:

```
36->16->4->4->2->1->0->0->NULL
```

Comment: If the first element gets deleted you need to update `*head_ref`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks. Fixed now. Unfortunately O(N^2).

Comment: +1 Awkward to get a new `prev` when you delete a node. This is a case where a double-linked list scales better.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Exactly. Using double-linked list it is possible to start the loop from the end of the list and delete unneeded elements. Complexity will be at most O(2*N) in this case (first run - find the end of the list and the second run - delete elements).

Comment: Thanks @Michael : After spending many hour on this problem i have came up with `O(n)` solution. And i have added this as an answer. Please see it, and if you find any mistake in that please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have reversed the conditions in your if statements.

```
if(current != NULL && current->next != NULL)
    return ;
```

Change it to:

```
if (current == NULL || current->next == NULL)
    return ;
```

And the other one:

```
  if(current->data > current->next->data)
  {
```

change to:

```
  if(current->data < current->next->data)
  {
```

Comment: Thanks, i have made these two changes in my code but it's not getting the desired result. I am getting some garbage value which suppose to be deleted from the list. Here is the my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9525857

Comment: @Shravan40 Your algorithm breaks the list if it deletes some element in the middle of the list. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what you mean?

```
if(current == NULL || current->next == NULL)
  return ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(current != NULL && current->next != NULL)
     return ;
```

I think you have a problem here. This exits in the first step. You may want to write

```
   if(current == NULL || current->next == NULL)
     return ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you told us more about what's not working, e.g. input and output, or compiler errors, or debugger stacktraces.

That said, I see that you are deleting the **next** value if it is smaller than the current (i.e. its its predecessor, its "left") which to my understanding is not the requirement. Shouldn't you delete the **current** if it is smaller than the next, as per requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Without reversing also it can be done.

**Here is the code**

```
public void delNodes(Node n){
   Node curr = n;
   while(curr != null && curr.next != null){
      if(curr.data < curr.next.data){
          Node temp = curr.next;
          curr.data = temp.data;
          curr.next = temp.next;
          temp = null;
      }else{
          curr = curr.next;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks M Hamza Javed for editing and improving the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone is looking for python implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def push(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp):
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next
        print()


def delete_nodes_with_larger_right(llist):
    current = llist.head
    prev = llist.head
    max = current.data
    while (current is not None):
        if current.data >= max:
            max = current.data
            prev = current
            current = current.next
        else:
            prev.next = current.next
            current.next = None
            current = prev.next
    return

def reverse(llist):
    current = llist.head
    next = None
    prev = None

    while (current is not None):
        next = current.next
        current.next = prev
        prev = current
        current = next
    llist.head = prev

if __name__ == '__main__':
    values_list = [[12, 15, 10, 11, 5, 6, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], [60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]]
    t = len(values_list)
    for index in range(t):
        llist = LinkedList()
        for i in values_list[index]:
            llist.push(i)
        delete_nodes_with_larger_right(llist)
        reverse(llist)
        llist.printList()
        t -= 1
```

Change the input in values_list according to your testcase.

Input:

```
12 15 10 11 5 6 2 3
10 20 30 40 50 60
60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Output:

```
15 11 6 3
60
60 50 40 30 20 10
```