# advancing a iterator by 1 in c++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to implement linked list which removes all the nodes which have a greater value on right side.

**e.g** The list `12->15->10->11->5->6->2->3->NULL` should be changed to `15->11->6->3->NULL`. Note that `12, 10, 5 and 2` have been deleted because there is a greater value on the right side.

So, the algorithm i thought was to create a list and then place two iterators at `beginning` and another at `beginning+1` and to check for the condition and remove the node if its greater.

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    list <int> a;
    list <int>::iterator it, b, c;

    a.push_back(12);
    a.push_back(15);
    a.push_back(10);
    a.push_back(11);
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(6);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);

    b = a.begin();
    c = a.begin()+1;


    for(it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
         if(*b<*c){
            a.remove(*b);
            b++;
            c++;
        }
        cout << *it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error

```
ctest.cpp:24:10: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’ and ‘int’)
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logic errors in your code:

1. What if a list will have two equal elements ? [list::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) will remove both of them. For example: `4->5->4->3` will be `5->3` that is not a thing that you expected.. Yes ?
2. What if the first element will be greater then second ? In this case iterators `b` and `c` will be not incremented at all
3. At the end of a list iterator `c` will point out of list and `if(*b<*c){` will fail

Maybe this - http://ideone.com/9NQAB1 - is what you wanted ?

Answer (score 2):

(Not sure about your logic) But, `std::list` iterators are [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) so `operator+` and `operator-` is not available here

You can use [*`std::advance`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Comment: i think `std::advance` has no `operator=` so this `c = advance(a,1)` fails

Comment: @c_coder Also, looks like your logic is wrong, See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22375145/1870232) for approach

Answer (score 2):

Lists iterators allow only the use of the `++` operators to move; the idea is that in a linked list the "natural", cheap operation is to move in single steps (moving of n steps is O(n)), so iterators allow just that.

So, in your code the fix is just to replace

```
c = a.begin()+1;
```

with

```
c=b;
++c;
```

In the general case, instead, when you need to advance an iterator of n places regardless of whether it defines the + operator, you can use `std::advance`.

Answer (score 0):

From C++11, you can use std::next, and std::prev on iterators to make it step forward or backward certain offset. Please refer to the documents and examples about [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [std::prev](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) in cppreference.

Answer (score 0):

Add Two Point

1

```
b = a.begin();
c = a.begin()+1;
```

b or c may be invalid , iterator can't be assigned like this, it's very dangerous.

2
you remove a elem when you traverse the list, And the iterator may be invalid after you remove.For example :

```
int myints[]= {17,89,7,14};
  std::list<int> mylist (myints,myints+4);
  for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << ' ' << *it<<std::endl;
    if( *it==89){
        mylist.remove(89);
    }
  }
```

outputs

```
 17
 89
```